# Are there new API's in Windows Phone 7 (Mango) which need new phone hardware?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Are there new API's in Windows Phone 7 (Mango) which need new phone hardware? Gyroscope stuff?

BTW, is AppHub the only Microsoft's official forum for WP7? Registration page is asking for 'Publisher name', website and payment? I just want to ask questions in the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A moderator on the Microsoft answers forum [said](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-sync/will-the-new-wp7-mango-be-available-for-upgrade/b95db123-8038-4ea1-afd1-ef1008719938) "all existing devices will get Mango". That seems to suggest they all support it. The one area that might require handset changes could be [language support](http://wmpoweruser.com/mango-upgrade-will-not-increase-the-number-of-languages-supported-on-existing-devices/).